# How to load data into dummy implementation of get_expanded_entityset in ABAP gateway?

Tags: abap, sap-gateway

We don't have any back-end or RFC to database table. So, we have made a dummy implementation of get_entity, get_entityset... such that we are providing data through debugging.

```
DATA Model:
Employee Entity { Emp_name, **Emp_id**, Emp_address}
Company Entity { Company_name, **Company_id**, Company_type}
Education Entity {qual_name, qual_type, **college_id**, year_of_passing}

Associations:
EmployeeToCompany;
EmployeeToEducation;
```

Though the data appears in internal table while debugging, it doesn't get displayed during output.

Answer (score -1):

The problem was: 
Associations(in Data Model)

EmployeeToCompany 1..1

EmployeeToEducation 1..1

And we implemented them as Table Type. Hence, it was unable to read a table into a structure.

Solution:

```
EmployeeToCompany 1..M
EmployeeToEducation 1..M
```

OR

```
EmployeeToCompany 1..1
EmployeeToEducation 1..1
```

and `implement these associations as structures.`